# How do I empty a list into a listbox with a method in a different class

Tags: c#

I have a class:

```
class Game
{
    public static List<Participant> Participants = new List<Participant>();
    public static List<SummonerStats> SummonerStatsList = new List<SummonerStats>();
}
```

I have a form class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    APICalls a = new APICalls();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        a.FillParticipants(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text));
        a.FillSummonerStatsList();
    }    
}
```

I want to add each object in the `SummonerStatsList` in a `listbox`. I could do this by looping through each object in the list under the button2_Click method but I would rather not have any code in my interface.

How would I create a method in the Game class which returns every item in the list OR what would the cleanest solution be that allows me to keep my code and interface separate.

Comment: There are many patterns you could apply. Databindig (make it, or wrap it in an ObservableCollection), MVVM, events, and so on, not all mutually exclusive. What have you tried?

Comment: I've never heard of any of those. The only thing I can think of is iterating through the list in the button_click method :(

Answer (score 0):

In-line with keeping your code and interface sepeated, you could accomplish this by doing the following:

1. Creating a method in the Game class that returns a list of type string (GetSummonerStats).
2. Use a [LINQ select operation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select(v=vs.110).aspx) on the list called SummonerStatsList, selcting a specific property(I have used "PropertyName" in this example) from the SummonerStats class.

   ```
   public static List<string> GetSummonerStats()
   {
       return SummonerStatsList.Select(x => x.PropertyName).ToList();
   }
   ```
3. Binding the values returned from GetSummonerStats method to the [Datasource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.datasource(v=vs.90).aspx) property of the ListBox (lstSummonerStats)

   ```
   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       lstSummonerStats.DataSource = Game.GetSummonerStats();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation of Vibhav Ramcharan 's answer, I have moved the logic of what to select from the list, into the button click method. This saves you having to create a new method inside of your game class..

If you were to continue adding methods to the game class every time you wish to populate a simple list in a form, then the game class would become overly bloated very quickly.

Essentially, what you are doing here is on request selecting from the SummonerStatsList only the properties that you require to populate your list.

You lose reusability with this answer, as the business logic is now inside of the button click event, however if reusability for this code is required, then move the logic into another method within your business layer, and do not bloat your game class which appears to be acting as some kind of repository.

```
public class Game
    {
        public static List<Participant> Participants = new List<Participant>();
        public static List<SummonerStats> SummonerStatsList = new List<SummonerStats>();       
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstSummonerStats.DataSource = Game.SummonerStatsList.Select(x => x.PropertyName).ToList();
    }
```

**Option 2 - Extension Methods**

Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

Overkill for your example posted above, however I do enjoy extension methods in general, they allow you to extend the functionality of pretty much any type of object.

Take your list for example, you could extend your Game class by creating seperate static class named GameExtensions and create a static extension method named GetSummonerList().

```
    public static class GameExtensions
    {
        public static List<string> GetSummonerList(this Game game)
        {
            return game.SummonerStatsList.Select(x => x.PropertyName).ToList();
        };
    }
```

To use this code, simply reference the game class and magically watch your new method appear;

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstSummonerStats.DataSource = Game.GetSummonerList();
    }
```